# Grails beforeInterceptor exceptions

Tags: grails

I want to specify more than one function as an exception to my beforeInterceptor, if this is possible can someone tell me the correct version of the syntax below?

```
def beforeInterceptor = [action: this.&auth, except: 'authenticate','index']
```

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following other features in Grails I would assume the syntax would be to use a List of Strings. So for example:

```
def beforeInterceptor = [action: this.&auth, except: ['authenticate','index']]
```